# How do I avoid to create a new lambda version when deploy by serverless framework with same image digest

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Everytime I deploy a Lambda function with the same image digest by serverless framework, serverless framework creates a new lambda version.
How do I avoid to create a new lambda version when deploy lambda function by serverless framework with same image digest?

Comment: If you need to remember (ot `tag`) specific versions, you may want to create an alias: https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-aws-alias

Answer (score 4):

According to docs, In your configuration file, set this provider-level option

```
provider:
  versionFunctions: false
```

Reference: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/#versioning-deployed-functions

> By default, the framework creates function versions for every deploy. This behavior is optional, and can be turned off...

Comment: Thank you dragonlobster. But I need the feature. I want to increment the version if different digest is specified.